# Steiner Tree for Directed Graphs

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I was using `steiner_tree` approximation algorithm in NetworkX library. While feeding it a directed graph it showed me an error that
`NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for directed type`.

I also tried to convert the following graph to an undirected type, and feed the same. But I'm losing some information like edge directions.

How can I extract Steiner Tree on a Directed Graph?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a solution to the directed Steiner tree problem from the undirected one. I would suggest to write out your directed graph and solve it with specialized software for directed Steiner tree problems. I don't know any
python package that is able to do that, the only software I know is:
https://scipjack.zib.de/